# Manipulate embedded / recreated web page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to "embed" a web page, and be able to manipulate the resulting page (`click()`, `textContent` etc).

I now understand that's not possible for security reasons. I tried iframe, embed, objects.

Is it possible to fetch the HTML of the page, insert that into a frame / div, and then manipulate that 'recreated' page? I guess I'd need to write a function to add parts to the code so it all looks like a faithful recreation (I don't think I need help with this part).

Comment: It's not possible in a browser, you'd need server-side code to do this.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for your reply! So, would it be possible to serve the page into the iframe via a proxy, and then have the page interact with the proxy served page in the iframe? Hope that makes sense - I'm still figuring out how this works exactly

Comment: Yes, a proxy would work for this.